# Play framework websocket is not sending messages to front-end when it happens

Tags: javascript, java, playframework, websocket

We have requirement to send messages to front end inside a for loop and we thought of using websocket to achieve this.

Our Js code (front end – here wsInterfaceBulkChecks is element id @html page)

```
var intWebsocket = function () {
var wsUrl = 'ws://localhost:9000/bvWSInterface';
var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? window['MozWebSocket'] : WebSocket;
var socket = new WS(wsUrl);
$('#wsInterfaceBulkChecks').data('wsObj', socket);

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
}
}
```

Router config
GET  /bvWSInterface  @controllers.admin.BulkChecks.bvWSInterface()

Java code

```
public WebSocket<String> bvWSInterface() {

        return new WebSocket<String>() {
            // called when websocket handshake is done
            public void onReady(WebSocket.In<String> in, WebSocket.Out<String> out) {

                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    out.write("Count: " + i);
                    try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Problem is it prints 0 to 4 at once at html debugger window (without any delays – websocket is sending all 4 at once to console). Our expectation as below

Print 0 -> wait for 2 seconds

Print 1 -> wait for 2 seconds etc.

Why web socket is sending all 0-4 messages a once to front end? (We believe it should send when it happens - 2 seconds break between message sending to front-end ). Please help us to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                         out.write("Count: " + i);
                         try {
                           Thread.sleep(2000);
                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                         }          
                      }
                     }
  }).start();
```

Comment: tx for the help. I will give it a try.